# Exercise 4 Hungerford's Algebra IV.3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

Following is from Hungerford's book of Algebra, Exercise 4 page 189 :

> Let R be a principal ideal domain, A a unitary left R-module, and p \in R a. prime (= irreducible). Let pA = {pa | a \in A} and A[p] = {a \in A | pa = 0}.
> (c) A/pA is a vector space over R/(p), with (r + (p))(a + pA) = ra + pA.
> (d) A[p] is a vector space over R/(p), with (r + (p))a = ra.

I could solve Items (a) and (b). For Items (c) and (d) (quoted above) My first idea is to show that for (c) : (r+(p))(a + pA)   = ra +pA is well-defined and for (d) : for r+(p) \in R/(p) and a \in A[p] : (r+(p))a    = ra, but I don't know if this is a right track to build on them the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The four items in Exercise 4 page 189 Hungerford's Algebra book can be solved essentially by applying the definitions.

For **item (c)**:  We have two operations in $A/pA$

1. for all $a+ pA$ and  $b + pA \in A/pA$   ,  $(a+ pA) +  (b + pA) = a+b +pA$
2. for all $r+(p) \in R/(p)$ and $a + pA \in A/pA$ , $(r+(p))(a + pA)   = ra +pA$.

It is easy to prove that those two operations are well-defined.  That means:

1. if  $a+ pA = a'+ pA$  and $b + pA = b' + pA$ then $a+b +pA = a'+b' +pA$
2. if $r+(p)=r'+(p)$ and $a+ pA = a'+ pA$ then $ra +pA = r'a' +pA$.

Then, check that those two operations satisfy the axioms of vector space.

For **item (d)**: The operations are:

1. if $a, b \in A[p]$, then $a+b$  is just the addition in $A$.
2. for all $r+(p) \in R/(p)$ and $a \in A[p]$ ,  $(r+(p))a    = ra$.

It is easy to prove that the operations are well-defined:

1. if $a, b \in A[p]$, then $pa=pb=0$. So $p(a+b)= pa+pb=0$. So $a+b \in A[p]$.
2. $r+(p)=r'+(p)$ and $a \in A[p]$, we have that $r-r' \in (p)$. So there is $k \in R$ such that $r-r'=kp$. So, $ra-r'a = (r-r')a = kpa = 0$. So $ra=r'a$.

Then, check that those two operations satisfy the axioms of vector space.

Comment: I couldn’t show scalar multiplication is well defined in (c). Can you please give some hint? I tryed multiplying $r-r’=kp$ and $a-a’=pb$ but can’t reach desired result.

Comment: @user264745 , If $r+(p)=r'+(p)$ and $a+ pA = a'+ pA$, then there is $k\in R$ and $b \in A$ such that $r = r' + pk$ and $ a = a'+ pb$. It follow immediately that 
$$
ra=r'a' + r'pb + pka'+ pkpb  
$$
Now, note that $r'pb + pka'+ pkpb \in pA$, so we have that $ra +pA = r'a' +pA$.

Comment: Thank you so much.